# Could not find or load main class Platform during docker container running

Tags: java, scala, docker, sbt, akka

I am trying to run jar from docker by bash script, inside it I have param `-Djava.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification`, after run I get error: "Could not find or load main class Platform". After adding double quotes I get another err: "Could not find or load main class seconds". In script I have only 2 params with "seconds"

1. -Dakka.actor.deployment.default.within=5 seconds
2. -Dakka.stream.materializer.stream-ref.subscription-timeout=30 seconds

After adding double quotes to them I get err "Could not find or load main class seconds" ". How fix it?

Dokckerfile:

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java:8_server-jre
RUN mkdir -p /opt/encry
ADD 0/EncryCore.jar /opt/encry/EncryCore.jar
ADD 1/template.conf 2/startNode.sh /opt/encry/
RUN chmod +x /opt/encry/startNode.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["\/opt\/encry\/startNode.sh"]
EXPOSE 10001
```

startNode.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Options: $OPTS
echo 123
echo "java $OPTS -jar /opt/app/EncryCore.jar      /opt/encry/template.conf"
java $OPTS -jar /opt/app/EncryCore.jar /opt/encry/template.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

You should quote any value that contains or can contain a space.

So:

- `-Djava.specification.name="Java Platform API Specification"`
- `-Dakka.actor.deployment.default.within="5 seconds"`
- `-Dakka.stream.materializer.stream-ref.subscription-timeout="30 seconds"`

If it's passed from a script, escape the quotes by adding `\` in front of them or wrap the entire string in single quotes.

Comment: Thx for answer! After wrap with single quotes get err: "Error: Could not find or load main class seconds' "

Comment: Please edit your Dockerfile and the shell script into your question.

Comment: add files into question